# I can't set background in Midlet

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

Some people say you can't set background in Midlet and use canvas. I used canvas mode and search for add TextFiled  I can't do it because canvas is low level UI and drawing textfield

Can help me for set background in Midlet without Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set Background in Midlet. The reason behind this Midlet is not an Compoment it-self. Midlet is a framework that allows to code for J2ME/Java ME Applications. A Midlet it self holds the the project components like Forms, Canvas TextBox etc.

You can not set background in Midlet, but you can assign a canvas or form to it and set its background.

A Canvas comes in Low level UI, while TextFied is higher level UI, which requires a component like Form for hold it. So you can not draw/put TextField on Canvas.